# How do I find the closest n numbers to a given number at x distance from it?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

For e.g. I have a list of number like

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

And I need 2 numbers at 3 distance from a given number let's say 5,
so the output list should look like this

```
output_lst = [2, 8]
```

Here by distance I mean the distance on number-line and not in list index. So 3 numbers, 2 distance from 5 would give

```
output_lst = [3,3,7]
```

What I tired doing was to use nsmallest from heapq like this

```
check_number = 5

output_lst = nsmallest(3, lst, key=lambda x: abs(x - check_number))
```

But the problem here is that I don't know specify the distance. It will just outputs 3 closest numbers to 5.

```
[4,4,5]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) for that. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34835951/4099593) for more on list comprehensions.

```
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> given_numer = 5
>>> distance = 3
>>> [i for i in lst if abs(i-given_numer)==distance]
[2, 8]
```

The logic is quite simple, we just see if the absolute value of the difference between each number and the given number, if so we return the value. Similarly

```
>>> distance = 2
>>> [i for i in lst if abs(i-given_numer)==distance]
[3, 3, 7]
```

---

Let's complicate a bit and try to use [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) and closures. The code is:

<sub>Just to show that it is an alternative</sub>.

```
def checkdistance(given_number,distance):
    def innerfunc(value):
        return abs(value-given_number)==distance
    return innerfunc


lst = [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
given_number = 5
distance = 3
checkdistance3from5 = checkdistance(5,3)
list(filter(checkdistance3from5,lst))
```

Comment: @MaxU's suggested solution (subsetting array) is shorter, but I have a question about efficiency and other possible factors that I might be missing. Is subsetting an array somehow more problematic or slower at large scale compared to the list comprehension that you suggest?

Comment: @Jason Numpy is always better for larger lists. This is for a beginner level only. The same can be said [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37631458/grab-2-keys-with-highest-values-for-nested-dictionary) where Max's approach of using Pandas is faster. All in all, If you have a small list and care more about simplicity base python is better.

Comment: @Jason, i agree with  Bhargav Rao. List comprehension will most probably be faster for a smaller lists

Comment: @BhargavRao Thanks! That worked perfectly. My list has had less than 20 elements so list comprehension was the better choice than numpy array.

Answer (score 3):

numpy approach:

```
import numpy as np

check_number = 5
distance = 3
a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
a[np.absolute(a - check_number) == distance]
```

Check:

```
In [46]: a
Out[46]: array([1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

In [47]: a[np.absolute(a-5) == 3]
Out[47]: array([2, 8])
```

Timings (in `ms` 1/1000 seconds ) for differently sized arrays/lists:

```
In [141]: df
Out[141]:
           numpy  list_comprehension
size
10        0.0242              0.0148
20        0.0248              0.0179
30        0.0254              0.0219
50        0.0267              0.0288
100       0.0292              0.0457
1000      0.0712              0.3210
10000     0.4290              3.3700
100000    3.8900             33.6000
1000000  46.4000            343.0000
```

plot:

[image]

bar plot for arrays with size <= 1000 (`df[df.index<=1000].plot.bar()`):

[image]

Code:

```
def np_approach(n, check_number=5, distance=3):
    a = np.random.randint(0,100, n)
    return a[np.absolute(a - check_number) == distance]

def list_comprehension(n, check_number=5, distance=3):
    lst = np.random.randint(0,100, n).tolist()
    return [i for i in lst if abs(i-check_number)==distance]

In [102]: %timeit list_comprehension(10**2)
10000 loops, best of 3: 45.7 ┬╡s per loop

In [103]: %timeit np_approach(10**2)
10000 loops, best of 3: 29.2 ┬╡s per loop

In [104]: %timeit list_comprehension(10**3)
1000 loops, best of 3: 321 ┬╡s per loop

In [105]: %timeit np_approach(10**3)
The slowest run took 4.48 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
10000 loops, best of 3: 71.2 ┬╡s per loop

In [106]: %timeit list_comprehension(10**4)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.37 ms per loop

In [107]: %timeit np_approach(10**4)
1000 loops, best of 3: 429 ┬╡s per loop

In [108]: %timeit list_comprehension(10**5)
10 loops, best of 3: 33.6 ms per loop

In [109]: %timeit np_approach(10**5)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.89 ms per loop

In [110]: %timeit list_comprehension(10**6)
1 loop, best of 3: 343 ms per loop

In [111]: %timeit np_approach(10**6)
10 loops, best of 3: 46.4 ms per loop

In [112]: %timeit list_comprehension(50)
10000 loops, best of 3: 28.8 ┬╡s per loop

In [113]: %timeit np_approach(50)
10000 loops, best of 3: 26.7 ┬╡s per loop

In [118]: %timeit list_comprehension(40)
The slowest run took 6.61 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 9.89 ┬╡s per loop

In [119]: %timeit np_approach(40)
The slowest run took 8.87 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 10.2 ┬╡s per loop

In [120]: %timeit list_comprehension(30)
10000 loops, best of 3: 21.9 ┬╡s per loop

In [121]: %timeit np_approach(30)
10000 loops, best of 3: 25.4 ┬╡s per loop

In [122]: %timeit list_comprehension(20)
100000 loops, best of 3: 17.9 ┬╡s per loop

In [123]: %timeit np_approach(20)
10000 loops, best of 3: 24.8 ┬╡s per loop

In [124]: %timeit list_comprehension(10)
100000 loops, best of 3: 14.8 ┬╡s per loop

In [125]: %timeit np_approach(10)
10000 loops, best of 3: 24.2 ┬╡s per loop
```

**Conclusion:** numpy approach is faster compared to list comprehension approach for larger lists, for very small lists (less than 50 elements) it might be other way around

Comment: @BhargavRao, i've updated my answer. BTW, do you know how may avoid `caching` in numpy solution?

Comment: Sorry, Not much of a `numpy` (nor a IPython) person. A related post is [Completely disable IPython output caching](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20814887). And thanks for the update